# Attaching a Glue trigger to a workflow in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-cdk, aws-glue-workflow

I created a workflow and a trigger in CDK, but when I look at the console, the workflow is empty. Any ideas about how to attach my trigger to my workflow?

```
    my_workflow = glue.CfnWorkflow(
        self,
        "MyWorkflow"
    )

    my_trigger = glue.CfnTrigger(
        self,
        "My Trigger",
        actions=[
            glue.CfnTrigger.ActionProperty(
                crawler_name=my_crawler.name
            )],
        type='ON_DEMAND',
        workflow_name=my_workflow.name,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the trigger wont show up in the workflow alone, you need some source, or job, or something to connect the trigger to in order for it to appear

Comment: Since you're not exactly sure, could you post your suggestion as a comment instead of an answer?